# What does the php function 'overload' do?

Tags: php, methods

According to the PHP documentation:

> The overload() function will enable property and method call overloading for a class identified by class_name.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.overload.php

But what does that mean exactly? Does it mean I can do proper overloading on that class (like Java's overloading)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It basically enables the [magic accessor methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) such as `__get()`, `__set()`, etc.

Since PHP5 this is no longer necessary and enabled by default. In fact, you can't switch it off ;-)